# How to mock Spring Message Resource inside another Mock class with Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

In my test when I assert de exception message I'm getting `null`

I'm not getting mock the message inside Service.... :(

I have:

My test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceImpl service;

    @Mock
    private Message message;

    public static final String REQUIRED_FIELD = "required.field";

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        when(message.getMessage(eq(REQUIRED_FIELD), any(List.class))).thenReturn(REQUIRED_FIELD);

        System.out.println(message.getMessage(REQUIRED_FIELD, new ArrayList()));
    }

    @Test(expected = MyException.class)
    public void testCancel_shouldValidCancellation_and_ThrowTicketException_with_RequiredFieldMessage() {
        try {
            Object object = //... new object
            service.do(object);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            assertEquals(REQUIRED_FIELD, e.getMessage()); // <-- e.getMessage return null!!!
        }
    }
}
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    @Autowired
    Message message;

    @Override
    public Object do(Object object) {
        if(object.getSomeAttribute() == null)) {
            throw new MyException(message.getMessage("required.field", "attribute"));
        }

        //doSomething...
        return something;
    }
}
```

In the `setUp()` of test the `printLn()` prints `required.field` but I can't use `message` of `Service`!!

Can someone help me?

Comment: `private serviceImpl service;` is this a typo or a different class?

Comment: Sorry, just wrong write.. edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard tell for sure, without knowledge about the interface of `Message`, but it is easy to spot that you configure mock object to stub method with signature `getMessage(String, List)`:

```
when(message.getMessage(eq(REQUIRED_FIELD), any(List.class))).thenReturn(REQUIRED_FIELD);
```

However, `ServiceImpl` uses `getMessage(String, String)`. The default value which is returned by mock in this case is `null`. You have to configure mock object properly.